# How to explicitly specify map node or reduce node in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

is there any .xml file or something similar which explicitly specify that are nodes where I want to run Map task or Reduce Task. if this is hadoop architecture dependent then how can specify nodes.

Comment: Is your choice of node 'job specific' or for the entire cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such feature.

I doubt if such a feature will ever be created because this would break the scalability and fault tolerance properties.

Comment: @Chris White
yes my choice of nodes is "job specific".
If it is cluster specific than one can easily do this by setting maximum.map.tasks= 0 to all not required slave nodes and set maximum.map.tasks = X(say 5) at required slave node.

do u have any idea how can I do this for Job specific...!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need not specify the node on which you want to run the tasks. Hadoop map-reduce does it by itself.

Comment: Thanks to the_Silent_lord
but I am want to explicitly define the nodes where hadoop should run Map task or Reduce Task for load balancing when integrating hadoop with another DFS Architecture...Pls tell me if there is a way to do so..and thankx again for ur response...